# Google Authentication with Custom App Name

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, google-plus

My website asks for Google+ authentication as follows -

[image]

However, I would like to make it look like to stack overflow -

[image]

There are two things to do -

1) Change `This app` to `My App Name`

2) I only want to have `View your email address` and `View your basic profile info`

I am using Google Plus Sign In with following scopes - 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

I learned from https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

Answer (score 0):

The permissions you're asking for depend on the scope you're requesting. So if you just want basic profile information and the user's email address, you need the scopes `profile` and `email`. See https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes for details.

To change the labeling, you must provide that information in the developer's console. Make sure all your information is filled out under *Apis & Auth* -> *Consent screen*. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#consentpageexperience for details.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Google+ Sign-In as per their recommendation not OAuth2. In the consent screen, I cannot change Application Name.